# Qt - Get numbers in specific area (from QLineEdit)

Tags: qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qlineedit, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget with some columns and rows and want to add a filter for a particular column.

For that, I've added a QLineEdit in my Window. 
I'm already able to filter the rows, when I add only one number in the QLineEdit:

```
for(int i=0; i<tableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
{
    if(!tableWidget->item(i, column)->text().contains(lineEdit->text()))
    {
        tableWidget->hideRow(i);
    }
}
```

(The slot is connected to the textEdited-Signal of the LineEdit)

What I want to do now:
When I write something like this in the QLineEdit: 10-30; Hide all rows, which doesnt have the number between 10 and 30 (>=10; <=30).

Somebody has an idea, how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my decision.

Check if lineEdit text contains two numbers.

```
QString test = ui->lineEdit->text();
QStringList lst = test.split('-');
    if (lst.size() == 2)
```

Transform they in to integers.

```
int low = QString(lst[0]).toInt(), high = QString(lst[1]).toInt();
```

Now let's go to tableWidget and drop in less than or equal to these two numbers.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    int row = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(row);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(i)));
}

connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, [=](const QString &test) {
    QStringList lst = test.split('-');
    if (lst.size() == 2) {
        int low = QString(lst[0]).toInt(), high = QString(lst[1]).toInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); i++) {
            int temp = ui->tableWidget->item(i, 0)->text().toInt();
            if (temp < low || temp > high) {
                ui->tableWidget->hideRow(i);
            } else {
                ui->tableWidget->showRow(i);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works perfect! Nearly had the same solution :P    Thank you!!